# Inequality involving $\arcsin$: step in a proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

I am reviewing a proof in a textbook of a calculus theorem. In one step of it the author establishes the following inequality and I don't know how it can be justified:
$$\frac{1}{|\arcsin(x^2+y^2+x)-\arcsin(x)|}<\frac{1}{|(x^2+y^2+x)-x|}.$$
I don't get which relationship between the $\arcsin(x)$ and $x$ is using. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: "Revising" means to re-examine and make alterations. You probably meant "reviewing". "To prove" is the verb; the noun is "proof".

Answer (score 2):

Note
$$ |\sin(a)-\sin(b)|\le|a-b|. $$
Note letting $a=\arcsin(x^2+y^2+x), b=\arcsin(x)$ in it, one has
$$ |(x^2+y^2+x)-x|\le|\arcsin(x^2+y^2+x)-\arcsin(x)| $$
which is the same as your inequality. The "=" sign holds iff $x^2+y^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the inequality as
$$
{|\arcsin(x^2+y^2+x)-\arcsin(x)|}>{|(x^2+y^2+x)-x|}
$$
suggests that this should be about the Mean Value Theorem. We have, since $\arcsin'x=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$,
$$
\arcsin(x^2+y^2+x)-\arcsin(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}\,(x^2+y^2+x-x),
$$
for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $x+x^2+y^2$. Since the domain of $\arcsin$ is $[-1,1]$, we need to assume that $x\geq-1$ and $x+x^2+y^2\leq 1$. Hence $\xi^2\in(0,1)$, and then $\frac1{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}>1$. Then
$$
|\arcsin(x^2+y^2+x)-\arcsin(x)|>|x^2+y^2+x-x|.
$$